# PowerShell: Rotate multiple image files and save them to a directory with new name

Tags: variables, powershell, rotation, pipe

I'm pretty new to powershell (I just took a semester at our local college). I have a directory with a lot of image files (.WMF) constantly being updated and I need to write a script that will take these files, save them to a new directory, and rotate them 90 degrees with "_90.wmf" added to the ending. I have been searching for a while and came up with a little code that will rotate the image but I can't get it to save to the new directory. Any help?

```
if (Test-Path J:\CutRite\v90\Import\MV_Nest_PTX_copy)

{

   [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

   foreach($file in (ls "J:\CutRite\v90\Import\MV_Nest_PTX_copy\*.wmf")){

       $convertfile = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($file.Fullname)

       $convertfile.rotateflip("Rotate90FlipNone")

       $newfilname = ($file.Fullname)

       $convertfile.Save($newfilname, "wmf")

       $file.Fullname

   }  

}
else
{
   Write-Host "Path not found."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there, you just need to create the new filename correctly:

```powershell
if (Test-Path J:\CutRite\v90\Import\MV_Nest_PTX_copy)
{
   [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
   foreach($file in (ls "J:\CutRite\v90\Import\MV_Nest_PTX_copy\*.wmf")){
       $convertfile = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($file.Fullname)
       $convertfile.rotateflip("Rotate90FlipNone")
       $newfilename = $file.Fullname.replace(".wmf","_90.wmf")
       $convertfile.Save($newfilname)
   }  
}
```

You can use the `replace` method of System.String to change `.wmf` to `_90.wmf` and store that in the `$newfilename` variable, then save the image using that name.

Also, not sure why you're loading `System.Windows.Forms` - unless you're using it in a snippet you've not included you don't need it for this.

#### Update:

If you wanted to save to a different directory altogether:

```powershell
$newfilename = "C:\path\to\new\dir\" + $file.name.replace(".wmf","_90.wmf")
```

Comment: Thank you! One last thing, how can I redirect these new rotated files to a different directory than they are currently stored in?

Comment: See the edit and note the use of `$file.name` instead of `$file.fullname` in this scenario.